# Is it possible to SET settings while logging using clickhouse-client?

Tags: clickhouse

I want to add a new Setting to Clickhouse codebase.
Now after doing the changes and compiling Clickhouse I want to test it.

Can I set that setting during authentication using clickhouse-client?

eg let's say there is a setting named **max_concurrent_queries_for_user**

```
./clickhouse-client --port 6667 --send_logs_level=trace SET max_concurrent_queries_for_user=100
```

I can log in like this, but now sure if the setting is applied or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[clickhouse-client](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/interfaces/cli/) has a rich set of options.

To get a full list of available options run the command:

```sh
clickhouse-client  --help

Main options:
...
  --max_concurrent_queries_for_user arg The maximum number of concurrent 
                                        requests per user.
  --insert_deduplicate arg              For INSERT queries in the replicated 
                                        table, specifies that deduplication of 
                                        insertings blocks should be preformed
...
*/
```

The option **--max_concurrent_queries_for_user arg** defines the "The maximum number of concurrent requests per user".